# Recreating a CSS Grid layout with Flexbox

Tags: css, flexbox, grid, css-grid

This is a simple layout I've created using CSS Grid for a website that displays events in a list format. The info area contains the date, and there are two more areas for content and a featured image. Using `grid-row` and `order` this can be done in relatively few lines.

I'm trying to improve my skills with Flexbox and tried to recreate the same layout (with similar adjustments to the layout depending on breakpoint) and failed. If someone could point me in the right direction or provide a similar example, I would truly appreciate it!

Code is here: https://codepen.io/mwaterous/pen/OrPmLL

Comment: What was your code for flexbox? It doesn't matter that you "failed". If you post it, we can offer suggestions on what to improve. Alternatively, I can give you the solution but I am afraid it will not help as much.

Comment: Here's what I thought would work: https://codepen.io/mwaterous/pen/LMEOrZ

Comment: Keeping in mind that last codepen is a living workspace, so I've modified it a few times with new ideas since I originally posted the comment. :|

Comment: That's one of the reasons SO discourages simply pasting CodePen link without additional code in the question/answer body. I am preparing an answer for you. There are a few different solutions. Do we assume that HTML cannot be changed? If you have 3 siblings within the same parent, it makes it a bit more complicated for the flexbox solution for tablet (as you have probably figured out already). If you can group HTML differently, it makes it much easier.

Comment: I didn't realize it was discouraged! I started to embed it using SO's interface but the viewport seemed to remain a constant size. Apologies! On with the show, I'm looking for the best solution, so if that requires changing the structure of the HTML I'm definitely open to that.

Comment: I figured out a solution based on restructuring the HTML surrounding the content divs: https://codepen.io/mwaterous/pen/GPJrMr and I'm definitely curious if this is up the same alley as what you were envisioning.

Comment: That's exactly the way to do it. You have some redundant CSS code, but you've got the point. Sorry that you're waiting for an answer. Coming soon. :)

Comment: No rush or expectation, I appreciate the personal time you've spent on this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm glad that you have figured out one of the ways to achieve this (with restructured HTML). If, for any reason, you are stuck with HTML which you cannot change, this could be one of the solutions.

**Disclaimer:**
The main challenge (and the question really) was how to achieve 2-dimensional layout (easily achieved with CSS grid) if we have 3 sibling divs within one parent and we are to use flexbox.

The biggest advantage of css grid over flexbox is that it allows you to manipulate content in 2 dimensions. My solution to achieve that using flexbox needed a "help" of absolute positioning, but it does the trick. I've intentionally left some parts of the code commented out to show you alternatives, and I've tried to include some useful comments.
Unfortunately, code snippet doesn't allow scss code, so I'll include it in the body along with this: https://codepen.io/nemanjaglumac/pen/OrVgLR

```
// HTML CODE
<section class="container">
  <div class="cell info">.info</div>
  <div class="cell main">.main</div>
  <div class="cell image">.image</div>
</section>
```

One option for css.

```
// SCSS CODE
// GLOBAL VARIABLES
$main-color: #fff;

*,
*:before,
*:after {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

html {
  background: linear-gradient(-20deg, #00b09b, #96c93d);
  min-height: 100vh;
  font-family: Ubuntu, sans-serif;
  font-size: 18px;
  text-shadow: 1px 1px 0 #000;
  color: $main-color;
  text-align: center;
}

.cell {
  background-color: rgba($main-color, 0.15);
  border: 1px solid $main-color;
  border-radius: 2px;
  padding: 20px;
  margin: 10px;
  text-align: center;

  &:hover {
    background-color: rgba($main-color, 0.25);
  }
}

@media screen and (min-width: 768px) {
  .container {
    display: flex;
    flex-flow: wrap-reverse; // this has saved us 3 lines of code (flex-direction: row [1], flex-wrap: wrap [2], and then later we would have to set order to -1 on .image [3])
    // flex-direction: row; // [1]
    // flex-wrap: wrap; // [2]
    position: relative;
    height: 300px;
  }

  .info {
    width: 180px;
    position: absolute;
    top: 0;
    bottom: 0;
    // left: 0; 
  }

  .main, 
  .image {
    width: calc(100% - 180px - 4*10px); // we need to count all four margins (2elements x left+right)
    margin-left: auto; // this moves elements all the way to the right. Alternative would be to set justify-content of the .container to flex-end, but then we would need to explicitly set .info's left position to 0 to "keep it in place"
  }

  // .image {
  //   order: -1; [3]
  // }
}

@media screen and (min-width: 1021px) {
  .info {
    position: initial;
  }

  .main,
  .image {
    margin: 10px;
  }

  .main {
    flex: 2;
  }

  .image {
    flex: 1;
    // order: 0; [3]
  }
}
```

Additional reading:

- [MDN Flexbox](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/CSS_Flexible_Box_Layout)
- [MDN Flex-flow](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/flex-flow)
- [Grid vs Flexbox](https://hackernoon.com/the-ultimate-css-battle-grid-vs-flexbox-d40da0449faf)
- [Flexbox Tutorial](https://scrimba.com/g/gflexbox)

Comment: And here is also an additional solution/Codepen for restructured HTML: https://codepen.io/nemanjaglumac/pen/gZpGEa. Both solutions have their pros and cons.

Comment: Incredibly helpful answer and comments, thank you. It definitely hadn't occured to me to try absolute positioning with the simplified html version.

Comment: @MarkWaterous I'm so glad it helped and even more glad you've been trying until you figured out part of the solution on your own. Usually people just want the quick answer. You reminded me of what SO is really about. Great start. Once again, welcome to the community.

Comment: Btw, I forgot to comment out two lines of code [1] and [2]. Sorry about possible confusion. Edited the answer.